# Google Compute Engine pricing programmatically from Google Billing Catalogue API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to pull Google compute pricing programmatically.  I am using
"Catalogue API" at following link.
https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api.

I found google cloud calculator  also refers to use the same API mentioned above to pull prices programmatically. But looking at API response, I cannot find information about Operating system and Maschine Types types IN json.

For example : "Maschine Type" is "e2-standard-2". I cannot find it in JSON respone from API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the details of the VM properties are not part of the results of the discussed API.  However, we can find the operating system details using the field "resourceFamily": "License" and Machine Type details using "resourceGroup": ["CPU", ”N1Standard”, “F1Micro”].

However, there is an open feature request for it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/111070261